# How to get 2d Annotattion of a rendered image in bledner using python script

Tags: blender, bounding-box, bpy

In blender i was able to get get bounding box data for rendered image , the bounding box data consist of top,left height and width. This gives a rectangular bounding box, which has some background image also. I want the exact bounding box value which contains no background image. I am working on an automation script which when run will give the rendered image and the bounding box detail.
Can someone guide me how to get the bounding box details .
Below is a sample json structure of how I want my bounding box details:

{
"id": 1,
"image_id": 1269,
"category_id": 4,
"segmentation": [
[
304.5,
212.3,
369.8,
236.8,
368.5,
281.3,
354,
289.4,
331.1,
283.1,
271.3,
323.7,
240.5,
310.5,
239.7,
268.4,
303.7,
229.1,
290.3,
221.8
]
],
"area": 8526.83,
"bbox": [
239.7,
212.3,
130.10000000000002,
111.39999999999998
],
"iscrowd": 0
}

bbox represents the format of top,height,width and left that we get from get_bounding_box().This has background image with it
I want the new bounding box data that is there is segmentation.This has no background image, it is the exact bounding box of the object

I was able to get the bounding box value (consisting of top,left, height,width(x,y,h,w)).
I was not able to get the segmentation value of the object , that would give me the exact bounding box.